# TransformedDistribution using $k$ iid random variables

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

How do I create a `TransformedDistribution` that uses $k$ independent identically distributed (i.i.d.) random variables?

For example, I can derive a chi-squared distribution with 2 degrees of freedom like so:

```
 In[1]:= TransformedDistribution[x^2 + y^2,
           {x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]}]
Out[1]:= ChiSquareDistribution[2]
```

Given an arbitrary integer $k$, how do I similarly derive a chi-squared distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom using `TransformedDistribution`?

Comment: `ChiSquareDistribution[k]`?

Comment: I mean, how do I derive it using `TransformedDistribution` (edited my question). I chose χ² as a simple example; my actual use case is a more complex distribution that doesn't already exist in Mathematica.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, you can simply use `ChiSquareDistribution[k]`, but in the general case, of the sum of  `k` variables distributed as `dist`:

```
iid[k_, dist_] := TransformedDistribution[
                    Sum[a[i], {i, k}],
                    Table[Distributed[a[i], dist], {i, k}]
                  ]
```

Comment: you asked for the sum of iid variables. If you want the sum of the squares of iid variables, add a square to `a[i]`

Comment: `iid[k_, dist_] := 
 TransformedDistribution[Sum[a[i]^2, {i, k}], 
  Table[Distributed[a[i], dist], {i, k}]]`

Comment: am I right to say that to get `ChiSqureDistribution[k]` one has to use only `NormalDistribution[0,1]`?